# Why this error "Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise." occurs on SonarQube

Tags: javascript, async-await, sonarqube

I'm querying a postgres db using async-await method.

```
export const queryByJobCode = async (jobCode) => {
    try {
        const text = 'select ...';
        const values = [jobCode];
        const jobCodeData = await dbConnectorUtil.pool.query(text, values);
        return jobCodeData.rows;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new DatabaseQueryException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, error.message);
    }
}
```

and I'm calling this method in another class.

```
const getMd = async (load) => {
    ...
    const jobCodeData = await queryRepository.queryByJobCode(jobCode);
    const filteredJobCodeData = filterDataUtil.getFilteredJobCodeData(jobCodeData);
}
```

If I run sonar scanner it is giving me an error saying that

```
"Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise."
```

Could you help me please? FYI this works fine in local environment

Comment: Seeems to be a linter error rather than a JS error. I see nothing wrong. Please share a bit more context (what are the `...`-s, where do you get the error?)

Comment: those are the rest of the code in that method. I have edited. please see

Comment: I don't get an error while running locally. But While running sonar scanner I'm getting this error

Comment: The error seems to mean that you *`await`ed something that wasn't a Promise.* However, in this code, I can't see any places where this could happen, so it probably comes from somewhere else.